# Use initial value after declared

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I have declared an array of objects inside ES6 class, and I try to find a way to use a parameter that I declared with another parameter that I declared.
Here is my code:

```
    searchModeData = [
    {
        maximumCharactersCount: 100,
        maximumCharactersErrorText: 'my count is #count#'.replace('#count#', this.maximumCharactersCount)
    },
    {
        maximumCharactersCount: 1500,
        maximumCharactersErrorText: 'my count is #count#'.replace('#count#', this.maximumCharactersCount)
    }
];
```

When I assign the value, I get the text with "undefined" value. Of course i can do the replace there, but I want to know if there is a shortcut to replace it already in the array

```
        console.log(searchModeData[0].maximumCharactersErrorText);
```

I get undefined value in this.maximumCharactersCount. There is a workaround that I don't know?
Thanks.

Comment: what exactly gives you `undefined` ? How are you trying to read this value?

Comment: Yes, sorry for that. I edit the question.

Comment: ah but that's not just JS. That looks like React

Comment: Yes but the question is related to javascript. Edited again.

Comment: Anyway, `this` does not refer to the object it's in. It refers to the _class_, or the _function_ it's in

Comment: Yes, I just realized that, is there any way to workaround it?

Comment: A workaround, no. A right way to structure your code, yes :) but I know almost nothing about React, so I don't have the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this.maximumCharactersCount gives you undefined because it does not refer to that object. Workaround would be to use function instead of value in maximumCharactersErrorText, but then you need to invoke it when you want to get value.

```
searchModeData = [
    {
        maximumCharactersCount: 100,
        maximumCharactersErrorText: function() { return 'my count is #count#'.replace('#count#', this.maximumCharactersCount)}
    },
    {
        maximumCharactersCount: 1500,
        maximumCharactersErrorText: function() { return 'my count is #count#'.replace('#count#', this.maximumCharactersCount)}
    }
];
console.log(searchModeData[0].maximumCharactersErrorText());
```